# delay in install_Referrer data

Tags: android, referrals

I have integrated the install referrer with a custom receiver. It does return the correct referral data but it is coming with a delay. Once the app is install, the custom receiver doesn't catch the referral for first few seconds, after that it receives the referral. I need to catch the referral data before the main screen appears (need to get the data and process it in the splash screen, due to which I have set the splash screen with a 10 seconds delay but still I am unable to catch the referral for the first time. Please advise. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this problem? I am having the same issue.

Comment: I did somehow manage to make it work but they upgrade of google play has again ruined it for me. Now I will have to work again to set it up.

Comment: The solution that I am going to use now is to make the processing asynchronous. So, I am registering the user using the normal workflow (irrespective of the referral code), and after registration update the referral information for that user whenever I get the INSTALL_REFERRER broadcast

Comment: Thats once way to do it, but in my case I need it as soon as the application opens.